# How to compile qmi_wwan driver on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: compiling, usb-modem, ubuntu-drivers

I've modifed [qmi_wwan driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/usb/qmi_wwan.c)  to make it work for my 4G LTE MIFI, and I want to compile and test this module. So how can I compile only related source files to make it work?

Comment: Is your modification to simply add a new usb.id; something like 12ab:34cd?

Comment: @chili555 I just want to test whether it works. I've also modified `usb/serial/option.c` file.